# How is the pressure term being generated?

Tags: general-relativity, velocity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, phase-space

### Background

So my understanding is that one can start with a stress energy tensor for many point particles:

$$T^{\alpha \beta} = \sum_{i} \frac{E}{c^2} v^{\alpha} (t) v^{\beta} (t) \delta(x-x_i(t)) $$

where $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the stress energy tensor, $E$ is the energy, $c$ is the speed of light, $v^{\alpha}$ is the $4$ velocity, $x(t)$ is the position of the particle at time $t$ and $i$ is the $i$th point particle.
Now if their distribution is isotropic then I can describe this system by dust:

$$T^{\alpha \beta} = \rho v^\alpha v^\beta $$

where $\rho$ is the density. However, we also describe a fluid's stress energy tensor using this:

$${T'}^{\mu \nu} = \int \frac{p^{\mu}\otimes p^{\nu}}{p^0} f(x,\vec p,t) d^3p$$
And under isotropy recover:

$$ {T'}^{\alpha \beta} = (\rho + p/c^2)v^\alpha v^\beta + p g^{\alpha \beta}  $$

Where $g^{\mu \nu}$ is the metric and $P$ is pressure.

### Question

How is the pressure term being generated? I thought the phase space distribution described the distribution of point particles? I think I'm missing something?

Comment: The first expression is just SET of bunch of non-interacting point particles, so $p=0$ in this case. The second expression is just the continuum limit. I think the last integral form also implies dust like solution, I'll just verify

Comment: I think this link (in French) is related to your question (average value...): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_cin%C3%A9tique_des_gaz

Comment: @KP99 any progress?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Have a look at [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02697946)

Comment: Relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03944.pdf